# Move child element under the parent element by z-index and position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not good at CSS. While developing a mobile menu, I stuck in setting the required order of z-index.

**HTML CODE**

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul></ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Here `nav` is header and contains, logo, search icon and menu in `ul`.

**CSS code**

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  /*other properties*/
}
nav {
  /*css properties*/
}
ul {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  /*other properties*/
}
```

Is it possible to bring `ul` under `nav` but above `body`using `z-index` and `position` CSS properties?

I want to use CSS `transform` and `transition` properties to bring the slide down and up effect when clicking the menu icon. Since in current code, `ul` is sliding from top of `nav`, therefore it looks a bit of odd.

Comment: Have you tried giving the other elements a `z-index` value and see what happens? Test first.. then ask!

Comment: I have already tried. I have set z-index of `nav` to 1000 and position `absolute`. But still `ul` comes at its top.

Comment: `ul` is a child of `nav` so if you sett the z-index of `nav` and set `position` on `nav` and didn't do anything to the `ul`, then the `ul` is still going to be part of the `nav`.

Comment: can you set the full code of your issue ? transform creates a stacking context that you need to work with . as your code is, there is not much answer that will fit exactly your trouble ... possible & classic  cure is transform3d to send ul below nav ... 1px is enough

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way you could do it, but it won't have the best animation...
Give the `nav` a `z-index`, when you click the menu icon set the `z-index` of the `ul` to something less than your `nav`'s `z-index`. To make the animation a bit better you could add this CSS to it as well (only after you click the menu icon)

```css
ul {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
    /* Other CSS properties */
}
```

You could use `@keyframes` to make an animation that will make it go behind the `nav`. Something like this:

```css
@keyframes {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
    }
    50% {
        /* Just has to be some number less than nav's z-index */
        z-index: 1;

        /* The 100px is just some amount that will get the ul out
           of the way of the nav */
        transform: translate(0px, 100px) scale(0.9);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.9);
        /* I'm not completely sure that this translate will go
           back underneath or if the scale still needs to be
           there... just test somethings out with it to make
           it how you want. */
    }
}
```

The main thing that you need to do is give your `nav` a z-index and when you put the `ul` underneath your `nav` you need to change your `ul`'s `z-index` to a lesser number than you `nav`'s `z-index`.

Hope this helps!